# How to split a JSON array to multiple JSONs using scala spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

I have an array JSON as below format

```
{
  "marks": [
    {
      "subject": "Maths",
      "mark": "80"
    },
    {
      "subject": "Physics",
      "mark": "70"
    },
    {
      "subject": "Chemistry",
      "mark": "60"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to split each array object as separate JSON files. Is there any way to do this in spark shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode the marks array of structs, add an ID column, and write JSON files partitioned by the unique ID column.

```
df.selectExpr("inline(marks)")
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .repartition(col("id"))
  .write
  .partitionBy("id")
  .json("output")
```

Comment: Where is the df coming from ? What if I just have the json .